# How to remove particular text from the string after specific character in angular 8 using *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular, I need a help.

In my application I got some data using API response. its array of object format. so I used *ngFor iterate the data. it's working fine.
In the data, I have a value called email. so in an email (ex. mine@gmail.com), I need to show the name only without "@gmail.com or @yahoo.com" like this. I mean should show up to '@' only.
I tried the split method but here in *ngFor, I don't know how to use that.

anyone, please help me to fix this?

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let content of listContent.content">
  <p>{{content.email}}</p>
  <p>{{content.name}}</p>
</div>
```

This is my ts code:

```
fetchContents() {
  this.MessagesService.findAll(id).subscribe(data => {
    this.listContent = data;
  });
}
```

before rendering to the HTML I need to remove the text then need to show it here.

Comment: You can use a pipe so you'll be using it inside the ngFor loop

Comment: Osakr, Thank you for your response, can you give some more idea this? i don't know how to do that.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda in the interface I have given string only. I just need to show the HTML only like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try this?

```
{{content.email.split('@')[0]}}
```

Comment: this is what I expected. actually, I used this directly in response data using foreach method type. I didn't try this way. thank you so much!

Comment: Be careful calling methods/functions in the template. They get called every change detection cycle even if the value doesn’t change. This is why we use pipes.

Comment: That's why my solution is far better than this "workaround"

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need the use of *pipes*.

First we create our custom pipe which will be encharged of removing the domain part of the email.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'removeDomainFromEmail' })
export class RemoveDomainFromEmailPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
     // Do the stuff to remove the domain name in the value
     return value;
  }
}
```

Now that you have your custom pipe then you can use it in the rest of your app, so if you import it correctly into your component you'll be able to use it in the HTML like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let content of listContent.content">
  <p>{{content.email | removeDomainFromEmail }}</p>
  <p>{{content.name}}</p>
</div>
```

By using *pipes* your code will be more scalable and more readable.

Comment: thank u for your solution and a brief explanation, it's really helpful.